# Loading Spinner Vue when loading img from URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want get loader spinner when img is loading, but i don't know how this make.

there is no loader, but I debagged and true and false were written to the console, but there is still no SPINNER

```
<template>
    <div class="KingOfMountain">
        <Spinner v-if="isLoading"/> //// ERROR
        <div v-else class="container">
            <div v-if="!isEndGameKing" class="choices">
                <p id="score">{{ currentCountKing }}/{{ ALL_FILMS.length - 1 }}
                <p/>
                <div class="photos">
                    <div class="first__film">
                        <img :src="firstFilm.Poster" :alt="firstFilm.title" @click="chooseLeftFilm">
                        <p id="title--film">{{ firstFilm.title }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="second__film">
                        <img :src="secondFilm.Poster" :alt="secondFilm.title" @click="chooseRightFilm">
                        <p id="title--film">{{ secondFilm.title }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div v-else class="winner">
                <p id="winner--title">Победитель</p>
                <img :src="firstFilm.Poster" :alt="firstFilm.title">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import game from "@/mixins/game";
import Spinner from "@/components/Spinner/Spinner"; //all good in css . it works


export default {
    name: "KingOfMountain",
    data() {
        return{
            isLoading:false
        }
    },
    components: {Spinner},
    methods: {
        chooseLeftFilm() {
            this.isLoading=true
            this.redirectToResultKing() // it is method in mixins (all Good, it works)
            this.isLoading=false
        },
        chooseRightFilm() {
            this.isLoading=true
            this.firstFilm = this.secondFilm;
            this.redirectToResultKing() // it is method in mixins (all Good, it works)
            this.isLoading=false
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

and if i will use like this, it will spinner,

```
chooseLeftFilm() {
    this.isLoading=true
    this.redirectToResultKing() // it is method in mixins (all Good, it works)
},
```

// it will spinner forever

Please,help me . How better make spinner ?

my mixins:

```
export default {

methods: {
    updateFilm() {
        // Here i random take 2 images from Vuex and then them delete and etc...
        this.currentCountKing++;
        this.allFilmsKingCopy = this.allFilmsKingCopy.filter(val => val !== this.secondFilm)
        this.secondFilm = this.allFilmsKingCopy[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.allFilmsKingCopy.length)]
    },
    redirectToResultKing() {
        if (this.currentCountKing === this.ALL_FILMS.length - 1) {
            this.isEndGameKing = true
        } else {
            this.updateFilm()
        }
    }
},
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['ALL_FILMS']),
},
```

My Vuex:

```
export default {
    state: {
        films: [],
    },
    actions: {
        async getFilms({commit}) {
            const data = await fetch(URL);
            const dataResponse = await data.json();
            const films=dataResponse.data
            commit("setData", films)
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        setData(state, films) {
            state.films = films
        },
    },
    getters: {
        ALL_FILMS(state) {
            return state.films
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: the whole thing is in `redirectToResultKing()` - you need to explain better what is it doing. You're enabling and disabling spinner in the same method syncronously, that's why between renders you'll always have disabled state in the end.  Probably you need to set "isLoading = false" asynchronously as a callback when `redirectToResultKing` finishes. But it's unclear what your code is doing, how is it loading the images.

Comment: @Stalinko can you please recheck now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common approach is to load the image in an [Image object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) and then use the [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/load_event) to wait until the data has loaded and show a spinner in between. Then you can set the image url and the `img` will be updated immediately:

```js
const imgUrl = 'https://picsum.photos/200?random='
let imgCount = 0

const App = {
  template: `
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <div>
        <button @click="loadImage">Load new image</button>
      </div>
      <div v-if="isLoading">LOADING....</div>
      <img :src="src"/>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      src: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async loadImage() {
      this.src = null
      this.isLoading = true
      const img = new Image()
      img.src = imgUrl + imgCount++
      await new Promise(resolve => img.onload = resolve)
      this.src = img.src
      this.isLoading = false
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.loadImage()
  },
}
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

---

You could omit the Image object and use the `@load` event on the `img`, but this will briefly have spinner and image visible at the same time, unless you hide the image with `v-show`:

```js
const imgUrl = 'https://picsum.photos/200?random='
let imgCount = 0

const App = {
  template: `
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <div>
        <button @click="loadImage">Load new image</button>
      </div>
      <div v-if="isLoading">LOADING....</div>
      <img
        v-show="!isLoading"
        :src="src"
        @load="isLoading = false"
      />
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      src: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async loadImage() {
      this.isLoading = true
      this.src = imgUrl + imgCount++
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.loadImage()
  },
}
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```